# Running Python 2 Scripts after Python EOL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, kali-linux

I understand that Python 2 has EOL-ed and we are making a shift to Python 3. A bit of context, I own a Kali 2020 VMWare Machine that comes pre-installed with Python 3. As someone preparing for OSCP (Security Certification), I am trying out some vulnerable boxes. However, some of the exploit scripts run in Python 2 and I am having a hard time running these scripts.I also do some research on Incident Response on the side and running Volatility is also a challenge.

I have tried plenty of ways to get Pip installed on my Kali. Using the get-pip.py script and all. Somehow, I am not able to download the python 2 packages and when I use pip3 it says it is already installed.

Some of the libraries that I have issues with are the Crypto Library.

I also tried to use 2to3 to convert some of the Python 2 code into Python 3 but there are still some issues running it.

I do hope there's a solution for this. Was wondering if I can create a Python 2 venv to run Python 2 scripts. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sudo apt install -y python-is-python2
```

See https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/python3-transition/